# How to filter keyword for integer, string and integer, string with dashes and integer based on keyword

Tags: php, validation, mysqli, filtering, keyword-search

I have implemented the search whose work is to find out the property records from database. The search is somewhat totally depends on typed keyword from user.

Suppose,

If user types keyword like `1234` or `4775` or `773` it should search records from `zip` column from database.

Next, If user types keyword like  `6 S Surfway` or `70 N Grove St` or `1661-114 Old Country Rd` it should search records from `address` column only from database.

Next, If user types keyword like `Calverton` or `Freeport` or `Riverhead` it should search records from `town` column only from database.

So, my problem is I am unable to filter these records based on the keyword user types in. My issue is to filter keyword based records from desired columns.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$key        = $_REQUEST['keyword'];
$searchOp   = $_REQUEST['searchOp'];

if($searchOp==1 || $searchOp==6)
{
        $searchChk = "(`property_chk` = '1' OR `property_chk` = '6')";
    }else{
        $searchChk = "(`property_chk` = '$searchOp')";
    }

$data = array(
              'locations' => array(),
              'errors'=>array(),
              'success'=> true,
              );

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    $data['errors'][] = $db->connect_error;
    die(json_encode($data));
}

$index = 0;

if(intval($key) >= 3){

$zipQuery = $db->query("SELECT zip FROM tbl_property WHERE zip like '%$key%' AND $searchChk GROUP BY zip LIMIT 0,5");
if($zipQuery->num_rows>0){
    while($row = $zipQuery->fetch_assoc()){
    $data['locations'][] = array(
        "value"=> $row['zip'],
        "altValue"=> null,
        "display"=> $row['zip'],
        "type"=> "zip",
        "propertyIndex"=> "",
        "index"=> $index
    );
    $index = $index + 1;
        }
    }

}elseif (!intval($key) && count($key) > 4){

$cityQuery = $db->query("SELECT ste,town FROM tbl_property WHERE town like '%$key%' AND $searchChk GROUP BY town LIMIT 0,5");
if($cityQuery->num_rows>0){
    while($row = $cityQuery->fetch_assoc()){
    $data['locations'][] = array(
        "value"=> $row['town'].', '.$row['ste'],
        "altValue"=> null,
        "display"=> $row['town'].', '.$row['ste'],
        "type"=> "city",
        "propertyIndex"=> "",
        "index"=> $index
    );
    $index = $index + 1;
        }
    }

}elseif (count($key) > 1){

$addrQuery = $db->query("SELECT addr FROM tbl_property WHERE addr like '%$key%' AND $searchChk GROUP BY addr LIMIT 0,5");
if($addrQuery->num_rows>0){
    while($row = $addrQuery->fetch_assoc()){
    $data['locations'][] = array(
        "value"=> $row['addr'],
        "altValue"=> null,
        "display"=> $row['addr'],
        "type"=> "address",
        "propertyIndex"=> "",
        "index"=> $index
    );
    $index = $index + 1;
        }
    }
}
$db->close();

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with some regex testing. Assuming the rules you are stated are that strict.

```
$matches = array(); // We do not use it but has to be defined
if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z ])+$/", $key, $matches)) {

    // Do search by city here

} else if (preg_match("/^([0-9])+$/", $key, $matches)) {

    // Do search by postal code here

} else if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z])*([0-9 -])+([a-zA-Z \.])+$/", $key, $matches)) {

    // Do search by address here

}
```

Example regex fiddles:

Postal - https://regex101.com/r/qK8pL7/2

City - https://regex101.com/r/yS1oF1/2

Address - https://regex101.com/r/pZ7dT3/2

These examples assume Postalcodes are always numbers and do not contain ANY other characters. Cities are assumed to always be alpha characters and/or spaces any other characters would make the match fail.

Use the fiddles to update to possible other characters you want to allow to make for a better suited test for your needs

In stead of a open `else` statement, you could also create a regex for address. That would be a little more tricky though and perhaps not applicable

Comment: Can we try `regex` for `address` as well?

Comment: you did some mistake Sir. For `postal` it should be: `} else if (preg_match("/^([0-9])*$/", $key, $matches)) {` and for `city` it should be: `if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z ])*$/", $key, $matches)) {`

Comment: Yup i swapped the regexes sorry. But the concept works for you? Will update the answer

Comment: getting closer Sir. May I have for `address` as well?

Comment: The given formats are the only different types that are possible?

Comment: Updated the answer. Also updated all other regex's to make them better. Replace `*` with `+` to change from `0` or more to `1` or more

Comment: These are number of possibilities in `address` like `85-10 151st Ave` or `70 N Grove St` or `11A Hemlock Dr` or `703 Fresh Pond Ave` or `B5 Schooner Ln` or `91 W. Parkview Dr` or `2105 Wallace Ave` or `1661-43 Old Country Rd` or `85-10 151 Ave`

Comment: All cases will now be met. This is as far as i go with my answer if that is ok with you? The answer now gives a lot of insight on how to fix it and includes links so you can do further optimization to the regexes

Comment: Yes Sir, it is ok to me. Most of the work has been accomplished using provided regex. :)